# How to create a dynamic breadcumb using angular

Tags: angular, typescript, primeng, breadcrumbs

I am using Angular 6 and PrimeNG.
I have developed a breadcumb. There are some inner child components as well.
How to set url parameter to the breadcumb label ?
I have tried

```
{
        path: 'school',
        component: InnerComponent,
        canActivate: [AuthService],
        data: {
          breadcrumb: 'school',

        },
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: schoolComponent
          },
          {
            path : 'select-options/:gradeId/:breadcrumb',
            data: {
              //breadcrumb: 'grade 1'
                breadcrumb:'{{breadcrumb}}'
            },
            children: [
              {
                path: '',
                component : gradeComponent
              },
              {
                path : 'class/:label/:utilType/:txnCode/:breadcrumb',
                component: classComponent
//                data: {
//                  breadcrumb:'{{breadcrumb}}'
//                }
              },
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
```

and it prints on breadcrumb as below

```
school -> {{breadcrumb}}
```

I want to print value of breadcrumb variable to be printed on breadcumb.

Thank you